# Recursively find all objects of type System.Web.UI.Pair in an object array

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have an object array that contains various types of objects (primitives, strings, other object arrays) at arbitrary levels of nesting.  I need to pull all objects of type `System.Web.UI.Pair` from this array and am having a heck of a time writing the method.  This is especially difficult because the Pair class itself can contain other Pairs or enumerable of Pairs.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

*(Original URL: [http://postimage.org/image/i7fuad3b9/)](http://postimage.org/image/i7fuad3b9/)_)*

Here's the method I came up with, but it feels inelegant and incomplete.  Any improvements, especially ones that can leverage LINQ are welcome.

```
   public static IEnumerable<Pair> Flatten(this object root, List<Pair> list)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return list;
        }
        if (root is Pair)
        {
            var pair = root as Pair;
            list.Add(pair);
            if (pair.First is IEnumerable)
            {
                Flatten((root as Pair).First, list);
            }
            else if (pair.First is Pair)
            {
                list.Add(pair.First as Pair);
            }
            if (pair.Second is IEnumerable)
            {
                Flatten((root as Pair).Second, list);
            }
            else if (pair.Second is Pair)
            {
                list.Add(pair.Second as Pair);
            }
        }
        if (root.GetType().IsArray || root is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (object o in (IEnumerable) root)
            {
                Flatten(o, list);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using this old, forgotten class with a tool like LINQ? You could replace it for example with a [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx).

Comment: One of our 3rd party assemblies is using the Pair class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider making this an extension method on `Pair` instead of `object`.  You could simplify it to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Pair> Flatten(this Pair p, List<Pair> toBuild = null)
{
   if (toBuild == null)
      toBuild = new List<Pair>();

   if (p.First is Pair)
   {
      (p.First as Pair).Flatten(toBuild);
   }
   else if (p.First is IEnumerable)
   {
      foreach (object o in (p.First as IEnumerable).OfType<object>().Where(ob => ob is Pair))
      {
         (o as Pair).Flatten(toBuild);
      }
   }

   //repeat for p.Second

  toBuild.Add(p);
  return toBuild;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var result = myPair.Flatten();
```

Or on an `IEnumerable<Pair>`:

```
var result = myList.SelectMany(p => p.Flatten());
```

Or on a regular `IEnumerable`:

```
var result = myList.OfType<object>().Where(o => o is Pair)
  .SelectMany(p => (p as Pair).Flatten());
```

Answer (score 2):

### Review

> Here's the method I came up with, but it feels inelegant and
>   incomplete. Any improvements, especially ones that can leverage LINQ
>   are welcome.

You could write it more elegantly by using recursion for your pair members.

> ```
>  if (pair.First is IEnumerable)
>  {
>       Flatten((root as Pair).First, list);
>  }
>  else if (pair.First is Pair)
>  {
>       list.Add(pair.First as Pair);
>  }
>  if (pair.Second is IEnumerable)
>  {
>       Flatten((root as Pair).Second, list);
>  }
>  else if (pair.Second is Pair)
>  {
>       list.Add(pair.Second as Pair);
>  }
> ```

```
if (root is Pair)
{   
    var pair = root as Pair;
    list.Add(pair);      
    Flatten(pair.First, list);
    Flatten(pair.Second, list);
}
```

You are right that it is incomplete. You are missing:

- pairs in dictionaries `KeyValuePair<T, Pair>`
- pairs in complex objects `Tuple<T, Pair>`, `MyPairWrapper`
- pairs in anonymous objects

*code*

```
public class MyPairWrapper {
    public Pair Value { get; }
    // ..
}
```

Your search strategy expects a tree structure, not a graph. In the following example you will get an infinite cycle.

```
var pair = new Pair();
pair.First = pair;
```

---

### Proposed Solution

I suggest to make a graph traversal walker that is able to deal with:

- cyclic graphs as well as trees
- any reference type you want to flatten
- any kind of sequence (`Array`, `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable`, `IDictionary`, ..)
- anonymous types
- common structs and classes (`Tuple<T1,T2,..>`, `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`, ..)
- complex types (traverse public fields and readable properties)

*Let's start..*

I adapted the method signature of the extension method and redirected the implementation to `ObjectGraphWalker`.

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this object root) where T : class {
        return ObjectGraphWalker.Flatten<T>(root);
    }
}
```

The graph walker `ObjectGraphWalker` traverses any graph (tree, acyclic or cyclic) and keeps track of `visited` objects to avoid infinite loops. Recursion is used to traverse sequences and complex objects.

```
public static class ObjectGraphWalker
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(object root) where T : class {
        var results = new List<T>();
        var visited = new ArrayList();
        FlattenWalk(root, results, visited);
        return results.ToArray();
    }

    private static void FlattenWalk<T>(object source, IList<T> results, IList visited) 
        where T : class 
    {
        if (source == null) return;
        if (visited.Contains(source)) return;
        visited.Add(source);

        // source is instance of T or any derived class
        if (typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(source)) {
            results.Add((T)source);
        }

        // source is a sequence of objects
        if (source is IEnumerable) {
            // includes Array, IDictionary, IList, IQueryable
            FlattenWalkSequence((IEnumerable)source, results, visited);
        }

        // dive into the object's properties
        FlattenWalkComplexObject(source, results, visited);
    }

    private static void FlattenWalkSequence<T>(IEnumerable source, 
        IList<T> results, IList visited) 
        where T : class 
    {
        if (source == null) return;
        foreach (var element in source) {
            FlattenWalk(element, results, visited);
        }
    }

    private static void FlattenWalkComplexObject<T>(object source, 
        IList<T> results, IList visited) 
        where T : class 
    {
        if (source == null) return;
        var type = source.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => x.CanRead && !x.GetIndexParameters().Any());
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        // search its public fields and properties
        foreach (var field in fields) {
            FlattenWalk(field.GetValue(source), results, visited);
        }
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            FlattenWalk(property.GetValue(source), results, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Test Case

Let's create a derived class `Triad` and a complex object `PairProvider` that has a `Pair` as property.

```
public class PairProvider
{
    public Pair Value;
}

public class Triad : Pair
{
    public object Third;
}

public class Pair
{
    public object First;
    public object Second;
}
```

Test method:

```
public static void Main() {

        var pair1 = new Pair { First = 1, Second = 2 }; // 1
        var pair2 = new Pair { First = 3, Second = pair1 }; // 2
        var triad = new Triad { First = "John", Second = "Doe" }; // 3
        triad.Third = triad;

        var dynamicObject = new {
            pair = new Pair { // 4
                First = pair1,
                Second = new[] { pair1, pair2 }
            },
            adapter = new PairProvider { Value = triad },
            items = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable> {
                { 1, new object[] { 1, 2, new Pair { First = 1, Second = triad } } }, // 5
                { 2, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } },
                { 3, new object[] { Tuple.Create<Pair, Pair>(pair2, new Pair()) } } // 6
            }
        };

        var flattened = dynamicObject.Flatten<Pair>();
        var count = flattened.Count(); // = 6

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to return anything. The list you initially pass in is a reference, which you can use after the function returns. The function can be of type `void`.
2. You can recurse on `First` and `Second`.
3. `root.GetType().IsArray` isn't needed

new code:

```
public static void Flatten(this object root, List<Pair> list)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (root is Pair)
    {
        var pair = root as Pair;
        list.Add(pair);
        Flatten(pair.First, list);
        Flatten(pair.Second, list);
        return;
    }
    if (root is IEnumerable)
    {
        foreach (object o in (IEnumerable) root)
        {
            Flatten(o, list);
        }
    }
}
```